# Directory tree listing, script does not work in csh?

Tags: variable, csh, tree

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

I found a command to display directory tree (see above), it didn't work correctly. It gave error message "Illegal variable name". I think the error is at `$` sign. How can I modify this command for cshell environment?

Comment: Other than escaping it?

Comment: I suspect that I am not the only one enjoying that the answer is given only a few characters further along in the question itself.

Comment: What is “directory command”?

Answer (score 1):

`:$` should be in single quotes to stop the shell from expanding it.

so `ls -R | grep ':$' | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

---

Your next thing to learn, is shell quoting, and expansions.

Also a lot of people consider `csh` to have been a mistake. It is full of odd inconsistent behaviour. Consider another `bash`, `ksh`, `fish` …

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a shell script you can use an external commands. 'tree' may be available in your environment, then it's easy.

```
tree -d
```